# FTP error: "get failed Failure writing network stream. No transfer to ABOR."

Tags: perl, ftp

Hi I am Trying to download file using ftp to a particular location in perl.

```
my $zipname = $ftp->get($filename,$local_dir)or die "get failed ", $ftp->message;
```

But I am getting this error.

```
"get failed Failure writing network stream. No transfer to ABOR."
```

If I am downloading the same file without using second parameter "$local_dir" in ftp get() then it is downloading it.
I need to download it to a particular location so have to use the second parameter.

I am using `use Net::FTP;`

and $local_dir contain path to my destination folder(where I want my file to get download).

Comment: If you are using `Net::FTP`, review the commands in the `SYNOPSIS` of the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html) for the module, particularly the `cwd` command.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to show more of your code. But if you are using `Net::FTP` then the second parameter to the `get` method is the path to the output *file*. Your variable name `$local_dir` sounds like you are passing a path to a directory instead

Comment: what do you mean by output file, and how can I get my file to get downloaded to a particular location.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out another way , It worked for me

```
$ftp->binary();
$ftp->port();

open TEMPFILE, ">$temp_path" or die "\nCan't open $temp_path for writing: $!\n";
binmode TEMPFILE;

my $dataconn;
my $buffer;

$dataconn = $ftp->retr($filename);
while ( $dataconn->read($buffer, 10240) ) {
    print TEMPFILE $buffer;
}

close TEMPFILE or die "Can't close $temp_path: $!\n";
$dataconn->close();


$ftp->quit();
```

Comment: This is ridiculously convoluted. It looks like you need `$ftp->get($filename, $temp_path)`